# Connecting to sql-server through jQuery-mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, jquery-mobile

I have html and jQuery-Mobile page,

I need to show table from sql-server (I have this table in my database)

How to combine the two things - `sql-server & jQuery-mobile` ?

**What to look for ?  do I need asp.net ? can I get any little sample ?**

I know to work with C# and sql-server like this:

```
SqlConnection Conn_SQL;
SqlCommand Cmd_SQL;
DataSet dsView;
SqlDataAdapter adp_SQL;

Conn_SQL = new SqlConnection(Connection); 
try
{
   Conn_SQL.Open();
   return true;
}
catch { return false; }

dsView = new DataSet();
SQL = "SELECT Serial FROM WorkTbl where Serial = '" + U_Serial + "'";
adp_SQL = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn_SQL);
adp_SQL.Fill(dsView, "WorkTbl");
adp_SQL.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shouldn't query your database client side.  It would be so easy for someone to go in and change it to whatever they wanted.

But a JavaScript example of how:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;InitialCatalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring); 
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof) 
{    
    document.write(rs.fields(1));    
    rs.movenext; 
}

rs.close; 
connection.close;
```